# regular expression that matches all substrings except if it's part of a particular word

Tags: javascript, regex

Match "or" in all cases except when it's part of the word "spork":

**or**ange
**or**
f**or**t
spork
w**or**k
sp**or**t
po**or**

I've been trying to play around with negative lookback, but I can't find a pattern that does what I want. Most related answers on here I can find seem to solve a different problem. JS implementation is preferred.

something like this:

```
/(?!spork)or/
```

**Edit**: I actually figured out something that works, but it doesn't feel like the best solution at all. Here it is:

```
/(?!sp)or(?!k)/
```

Comment: The easiest way is matching the word `spork` and capturing `or` (or vice versa, depends on the use case). `/\bspork\b|(or)/`.

Comment: This `(?!sp)o` will _always_ match since the engine is looking for the next series of characters to NOT be `sp`. And indeed, the next character is `o`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do it like this `(?<!(?<=\bsp)(?=ork\b))or`

see https://regex101.com/r/3zsWJI/1

or

this faster way `or(?<!(?<=\bspor)(?=k\b))`

see https://regex101.com/r/CUwgnp/1

The faster way explained here

```
 or                        # Match any 'or'
 (?<!                      # Look behind NEGATIVE assertion
                           # - This group's conditional ( == or != ) is checked
                           #   after its containing sub expressions are processed for a match
      
      (?<= \b spor )       # At the current position, i.e. after the    'or'
                           # check if there is a                      'spor'^
                           # behind.
                           # This starts 4 character positions to the left of 'or'
      
      (?= k \b )           # Then at the current position, i.e. after the    'or'
                           # check if there is a 'k' in front of it
      
 )                         # Finally, check if both of these sub-expressions matched.
                           # If they did then the ( == ) is alarmed,
                           # if they didn't, then the ( != ) is alarmed.
 
                           # This lookbehind assertion '(?<!  )' 
                           # does NOT want these two inner expressions to match !
```

Comment: Wow nice. I'm still trying to wrap my head around exactly what this is doing, but I think I mostly get it. I should specify in the OP that it should match the "or" in e.g. "work" and "sport" (matching the ending and beginning of "spork" respectively) which yours does.

Comment: I'll post up an explanation for you.

Comment: Btw, what makes the second one faster? regex101 says they both take ~0ms

Comment: A literal search is slower when an assertion (look behind) is placed before it as opposed to behind it. Could probably test them checking the PCRE engine. Fewer steps might be an indicator.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark as the answer if it solved your problem. If not, wait a while, something better might be posted.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Upvoted, but I have less than 15 rep.